# How to get the reponse code from Web API in React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to learn React. I created a POST method in my web API that returns an IActionResult

like so:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(Department model)
        {
            try
            {
                var query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Departments
                                (DepartmentName)
                                VALUES (@departmentName)
                            ";
                int result = 0;
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@departmentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.DepartmentName;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                Response.StatusCode = 201;
                return Content("Data has been saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return Content(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This method works fine. But I cannot get the "Content" of the response. This is how I consume this API in my react application

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:1173/api/Department', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
           },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            DepartmentId: 0,
            DepartmentName: event.target.departmentName.value
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        alert(result);
    },
    (error) => {
        alert('Failed in adding data: ' +error);
    })
}
```

With my Edits, I am now able to "alert" this => `function json() { [native code] }`

This is the result of the first ".then"

[image]

and on my alert, I get "undefined". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to "call" .json() and not return it:

```
 .then(res => res.json())
```

Instead of:

```
.then(res => res.json)
```

Comment: What do you mean Sir. How do I put in the "return". Can you please edit the code so I would know?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 just did, let me know if it is clearer?

Comment: I actually did t hat Sir. I just get  `f  json() { [native code] }`

Comment: If it is not clearer please provide a JSFiddle I can troubleshoot

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I just changed my WebApi from `Response.StatusCode = 201;
                return Content("Data has been saved");` to `return Ok("Data has been saved")`